Finding roots of the derivative of function with variable powers
I have this function $f(x) = r_\text{o1}\cdot\left(1-\left(\dfrac{r_\text{i1}}{x+r_\text{i1}}\right)^\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}\right)$.
I also have $g(x)$ with the same structure but instead of the variables being labeled as $1$ they are labeled as $2$.
I can compose the functions so that the output of $f(x)$ is the input of $g(x)$ and finally subtract $x$ to have a final function:
$$h(x) = g(f(x))-x = r_\text{o2}\cdot\left(1-\left(\dfrac{r_\text{i2}}{r_\text{o1}\cdot\left(1-\left(\frac{r_\text{i1}}{x+r_\text{i1}}\right)^\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}\right)+r_\text{i2}}\right)^\frac{w_\text{i2}}{w_\text{o2}}\right) - x$$
I now need to find analytically the maximum of this function. When w's are equal it is trivial. But when w's (weights) are different, I haven't been able to find it.
I can find the derivative of the function $$ h'(x) = \dfrac{r_\text{i1}^\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}r_\text{i2}^\frac{w_\text{i2}}{w_\text{o2}}r_\text{o1}r_\text{o2}w_\text{i1}w_\text{i2}\cdot\left(x+r_\text{i1}\right)^{-\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}-1}\left(r_\text{o1}\cdot\left(1-\frac{r_\text{i1}^\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}}{\left(x+r_\text{i1}\right)^\frac{w_\text{i1}}{w_\text{o1}}}\right)+r_\text{i2}\right)^{-\frac{w_\text{i2}}{w_\text{o2}}-1}}{w_\text{o1}w_\text{o2}}-1 $$ but finding the roots seems impossible. Once I set the parameters, finding the roots numerically is also easy with matlab, but I need the formula that gives me the maximum (i.e. the roots of the derivative).
Maybe there are some properties that I'm not aware of that can make this task simpler. The parameters fulfill these assumptions:
$$
0 \lt w \lt 1
$$
$$
w_\text{in} + w_\text{on} \leq 1
$$
To be clearer, any $w$ will be smaller than 1. The sum of any two $w_i$ and $w_o$ with the same numerical index will be also smaller or equal to 1.
All other parameters are natural numbers.
I've tried also setting these assumptions in matlab with no avail. Can someone guide me on what should I try next?
P.S. I need to have the formula to implement it in code. I know I can use some approximation algorithms such as the Newton-Raphson but speed is crucial so I'd rather have a formula.

If the exponents are arbitrary then I doubt an explicit solution exists. For a function of a single variable like this, fzero in MATLAB will likely be faster than Newton's method
